# Elementary OS guest additions does not seem to allow Clipboard sharing or Drag and Drop

Tags: virtualbox

Having issues with the latest version of Elementary OS in a virtual box running on a windows 10 machine. it does not seem to allow both clipboard sharing or drag and drop like most other ubuntu 18.04 based distros I've tried so far. I have made sure to enable them in my virtual box client for this virtual machine and I have reinstalled the VirtualBox additions twice now and restarted the machine multiple times as well.

Any help or way to report this to the developers?

Answer (score 0):

Solved this using those commands

```
VBoxClient --draganddrop
VBoxClient --clipboard
```

Comment: I've had issues in the past with VirtualBox and USB devices because my user wasn't in the 'vbox' users group. While not directly related, it doesn't hurt to look for this, too.